# Impossible to find ScriptForCreateDrop property in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, msdn

I am scripting a script who drop and create object in database (views, tables..)
Everything works fine... but i can't find the ScriptForCreateDrop in Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptingOptions dll.

This propert is in the official documentaion of microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0

Did you ever face this situation ? Do you know why i can't find it ? Already tried to install the latest version of this dll (from nuget)

Thx.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is here to be honest. I installed the latest version of SMO from Nuget and then I made a new Class and Sub and wrote this code `Dim scriptingOptions As New ScriptingOptions()
        scriptingOptions.ScriptForCreateDrop = True` And I receive no errors. The SMO version is `14.100.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug even in the latest SMO . V150.18178.0
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38383138--smo-scriptingoptions-scriptforcreatedrop-true

I was able to get around this using reflection and setting the property manually:

```
ScriptingOptions scrp = new ScriptingOptions();
var field =
scrp.GetType().GetField("scriptingPreferences", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
ScriptingPreferences sp = (ScriptingPreferences)field.GetValue(scrp);
sp.Behavior = ScriptBehavior.DropAndCreate;
field.SetValue(scrp, sp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the wrong nuget package/version installed.

Try installing this nuget package

Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects